# multiple json string in android

Tags: android

I have to return all my JSON string. For example I have one json string:

```
[{"Locationvalue":"Payroll  - 9","LocationId":"465","IsSelected":false}]
```

and also returned second JSON string:

```
[{"CC2Description":"Denver - DN","CC2":"DN","isSelected":false},{"CC2Description":"Las Vegas - LV","CC2":"LV","isSelected":false}]
```

ans so on.

In android I have written this:

```
JSONArray JsonObject = new JSONArray(JsonString.toString());

for(int i=0;i<JsonObject.length();i++)
{
   Log.v("log",  JsonObject.getString(i));
}
```

but I can only access one JSON array. I want other JSON array also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot decode multiple separate json structures in a single call. A JSON structure must be a complete proper Javascript object or array on its own, e.g.

Two arrays like this:

```
[1,2,3][4,5,6]
```

is invalid, because it's two separate arrays smashed up against each other. However,

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

is ok, because it's a single array that contains two separate child arrays. You can return multiple separate json strings, but they must be contained within a single structure.

Comment: {"German":["Hello","guten Morgen","gute Nacht"],"English":["Hello","good morning","good Night"],"French":["bonjour","bonne nuit","bonjour"]}